# YARP - Routing based on regular expression

Tags: .net-core, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

Is it possible to use regular expressions in Match-Path-rules to match general broader url-patterns and to be able to match very specific patterns. I dont want to use `{**catch-all}` but for example an ordinary RegExp like `/api/\w{1,3}-\d{1,9}` ...

Is this possible to achieve with Yarp in some way?

```
"Match": {
        "Path": "<Regular expressions here or ?>"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
"Match": {
   "Path": "/api/{path:regex(\\w{{1,3}}-\\d{{1,9}})}"
}
```

or

```
"Match": {
   "Path": "/api/{folder1:regex(^\\w{{1,3}}$)}-{folder2:regex(^\\d{{1,9}}$)}"
}
```